# Replace, all at once, rest of a group of words with span

Tags: javascript

In the following example, first I replace successfully the 'my own' with its own span `'<span id="sMyOwn">my own</span>'`. Next, I want to replace, all at once, the rest of the words (that is, 'This', 'is' and 'example') with a simple span. For this, I use the function fReplace, in order to do it conditionally according to @Abhilash comment that follows, but it fails. The second and the third solutions I applied are based on a simple loop solution, but they fail too. Could someone please help me. The last line is just to present the results.

```
<div id='MyOwnExample'>This is my own example</div>
<div id='AA'></div>

<script>
// 1st part: It works
    v1 = document.getElementById('MyOwnExample').innerHTML;
    const regex = new RegExp('my own', 'gi')
    v1 = v1.replace(regex,`<span id = 'sMyOwn'>my own</span>`)
    document.getElementById('MyOwnExample').innerHTML = v1;

// 2nd part: First solution that fails
    function fReplace(word, index) {
        const regex = new RegExp(word, 'gi')
        if (span.className != 'sMyOwn') {
            v1 = v1.replace(regex,`<span>${word}</span> `)
        }
    }
    v1.forEach(fReplace);
    document.getElementById('MyOwnExample').innerHTML = v1;

// 2nd part: Second solution that fails too 
const regex2 = new RegExp(word, 'gi')
for (word of v1) {
    if (span.className != 'sMyOwn') {
        v1 = v1.replace(regex2,`<span>${word}</span> `)
    }
}
document.getElementById('MyOwnExample').innerHTML = v1;

// 2nd part: Third solution that fails too 
for (word of v1) {
    if (typeof(span) == 'undefined') {
        v1 = v1.replace('${word} ', `<span>${word}</span> `)
    }
}
document.getElementById('MyOwnExample').innerHTML = v1;


// 4th part: Results
    document.getElementById('AA').innerText = document.getElementById('MyOwnExample').innerHTML;

</script>
```

Comment: how are you getting 'span' object in line 'if (span.className != 'sMyOwn')'

Comment: And you're setting "sMyOwn" as ID, not Class.

Comment: My thinking is to replace every word that its span is not 'sMyOwn'. But it does not work.

Comment: `v1` is a reference to an element's `innerHTML` and thus a string. Calling `forEach` on a string will go through each byte of the string, not each word.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey I think I understand you, but how I should do it ?

Comment: Get the original text, remove the "my own" text. Split the remainder on space and wrap them in `<span>${word}</span>`. Glue them all back together.

Comment: use v1.split(" ") to convert sentence into words before calling forEach.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey Ok, I see. This is a solution. If something else does not come up I shall run it. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code in your question you wanted to see the output in raw text and not in html but just incase you need it in html uncomment the last line.

```html
<div id='MyOwnExample'>This is my own example</div>
<div id='AA'></div>
<script>

/**
 First wrap the special phrase with a span as you want
 
 Now take out the special phrase and split the remaining text into array while you use '_' as the special phrase placeholder for later replacement.
 
 Replace each wrap each word with span as you want it
 
 Put them back while replacing the '_' placeholder with the wrapped special phrase
 
**/
const transformer = (word,specialPhrase)=>{
  const wrapSpecialPhrase = `<span id="sMyOwn"> ${specialPhrase}</span>`;
  const stripoffSpecialPhrase = (word.split(specialPhrase)).join("_").split(" ");
  const formed = stripoffSpecialPhrase.map(wd=> wd !=='_' ?`<span id='${wd}'> ${wd} </span>` : wd);
  return formed.join(" ").replace('_',wrapSpecialPhrase);
}

const aaElement = document.getElementById('AA');
const myOWnExampleElement =  document.getElementById('MyOwnExample')

const  phrase =  myOWnExampleElement.innerText;
const transformed = transformer(phrase,"my own");
aaElement.innerText= transformed; // This when you want it in plain text
/* aaElement.innerHTML= transformed; // This when you want it in html */

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A **regex** would be helpful in safely splitting the sentence by retaining group of words.

```js
const text = "This is my own example";
const yourHTML = text.split(/( |my own)/g)
    .filter(v => v.trim())
    .map(v => "<span"+ (v == "my own" ? " id='sMyOwn'" : "") + ">" + v + "</span>")
    .join("")

console.log(yourHTML)
```

Output:

```html
<span>This</span><span>is</span><span>my own</span><span>example</span>
```

Comment: And what if instead of one specific span like '<span id="sMyOwn">my own</span>' we have many as such ? This is what is I wonder. If there is a way to replace, all at once, by imposing criteria.

Comment: got your point. and you're right, will need to do conditionally. i've updated

Comment: @ Abhilash Exactly !!! This is what I wonder and thank you for helping clarifying it

Comment: when you have lot of words that need to be together, like "my own", store them in a object with key=text & value=id_of_element (like a dict in R). Sleek.

Comment: @ Abhilash I see what you are talking about. I shall wait if any other idea comes up and possibly I shall follow your recomendation. Thank you a lot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example:

```js
const v1 = document.getElementById('MyOwnExample').innerText;
const arr = v1.split(' ');

for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 let str = arr[i]; 
 arr[i] = arr[i].replace(new RegExp(str, 'gi'),`<span id='id_${str}'>${str}</span>`);
}

console.log(arr);

document.getElementById('MyOwnExample').innerHTML = arr.join(' ');

document.getElementById('AA').innerText = document.getElementById('MyOwnExample').innerHTML;
```

```css
#MyOwnExample span {
 background-color: #dedede;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id='MyOwnExample'>This is my own example</div>
<div id='AA'></div>
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your effort but your solution does not preserve the '<span id="sMyOwn">my own</span>'.